# How can I clean the VSCode, Code directory on a mac?

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

I have a MBP 2019 256 Gb variant. I'm in dire need to get some space cleared out. One thing I noticed is that VS Code takes up ~24 Gb of storage on my Mac as shown below.

[image: VS Code space]

How can I clear out the data in the `Code` directory? The files/folders within the directory are shown below. Thanks!

[image: Directory]